# WHy can't i delete from my database on sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite

```
@app.route("/delete/<id>", methods=['POST'])
def remove(id):

    connection = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    cur = connection.cursor()

    cur.execute('Delete from query_database where id == ?' (id,))
    cur.close()
    return ('status.HTTP_200_OK')
```

I want to delete lines off my database given the id.
example:

```
127.0.0.1:5002/delete/1
```

The error i'm getting is:

```
File "api_calls.py", line 65, in remove
    cur.execute('Delete from query_database where id == ?' (id,))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Sep/2018 18:33:56] "POST /delete/1 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a comma in the `cur.execute` line after the string and before (id, ). Try using the following

```
cur.execute('Delete from query_database where id == ?', (id,))
```

Answer (score -1):

With Django , to delete  your database  inside the server, you delete your model and then you run the  migrate and makemigrations.
To delete records you go through a form and post request. 
Hope it will help .....